# What is the difference between current and non-current liabilities?

Tags: stock-analysis

Take this page:

http://www.londonstockexchange.com/exchange/prices/stocks/summary/fundamentals.html?fourWayKey=GB00B1YMN108GBGBXASQ1

Under liabilities you have current and non-current liabilities. What is the difference?

Comment: This could have been included in your other question.

Comment: I got half way through doing it and thought people would have said it was two questions in one.

Comment: fair enough.  I suppose it could go either way! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Current typically refers to a time line shorter than 12 months.  At least that's what it means in the US, I'd imagine the same applies in the UK.

A current asset is something like cash, or a very short term security; a 9 month CD for example.  A current liability can be something like a payable to a vendor.

There is also a situation where you have the current portion of a long-term liability.  That could be the amount of a long term loan that's due in the next 12 months.